# Calculating the size of structure in bytes without using sizeof

Tags: c, sizeof

I am looking for a way to calculate the size of specific structure without using the function `sizeof()` in C.

Comment: why?...........

Comment: `sizeof()` is not a function.

Comment: I am bulding a real time system i dont want to call to another function because it going to spend more time and mem of the stack

Comment: `sizeof` is evaluated at _compile_ time (except for VLAs).

Comment: sizeof() is not a function,one unary operator

Comment: These comments give many help, at least you know now that you dont need that.

Comment: why people votewdown for this question , he ask a proper question????

Comment: And even more strange is the vote to close

Comment: pointer difference may be useful but not portable `int)(&ptr+1)- (int)(&ptr));`

Comment: I removed the C++ tag as the question only asks about C. I agree about the downvoting - just because a question may seem simple or the answer obvious, doesn't mean it isn't valid.

Answer (score 12):

`sizeof` is not a function.  It is evaluated at compile time so will not impact the execution time of your program.  It is correct to use it.

Also, stop premature optimizing.

Comment: This is the correct answer (and the one that should be accepted).

Answer (score 2):

From Mats comment:
You should not do that, because `sizeof()` is evaluated at compile time (except VLAs).